# Simple layman genealogy software

Tags: open-source, genealogy

I recently checked Gramps and Ancestris, both genealogy software. My requirements for a layman that has bad memory are much different from those that professional genealogy tools are providing.

I need tool for simply drag&drop persons to the tree editor and write names to nodes, something that you expect to use on iPhone (I used this platfrom just to underline simplicity of usage that you can find in iOS platform).

Effect of this kind of tree is to simply check is from time to time and remember what's your distant relative name, not to check his sexual orientation or something like the facts you can enter with genealogy software.

Comment: You used iPhone as an example - where do you actually want to run the app? Which o/s?

Answer (score 2):

If you want something very simple, I would use an online service rather than an installed package.

Try [Tribal Pages](http://www.tribalpages.com/).  It isn't drag and drop but you can easily set up a family tree.  As it is in the cloud, you can authorise family members to see the tree too.

The free version of the service will do what you want.  It does have paid-for versions with extended capability.